# Laravel - unable to save "0" in text not null column

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 10 with php 8.2 and I spotted a weird issue.
I can't assign `"0"` value to my model and save it in db.
I receive following error.

```
Attempt to assign property "content" on null
```

Some reason Laravel convert 0 to null.

I tried to cast that field "content" in model to string but no effect.

Do you know any why how to prevent it? And save this value in db text column?

Regards

Comment: could you send a sample of code. and pleas tell me about your database type and version.

Answer (score 2):

I think the model itself is `null`, that is why is telling you that a `null` cannot have properties.

If you are retrieving the model from the DB check if is not null with a `if` or `findOrFail()`.